# How to solve this series with a log on the denominator?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

So I stumbled upon a series I can't quite solve:

$$S=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n\ln(n)}\approx0.526418$$

Notice that if we generalize this:

$$S(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^x\ln(n)}$$

and differentiate with respect to $x$, we get

$$S'(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^x}=\eta(x)-1$$

where $\eta$ is the Dirichlet eta function.  It then seems natural to try and integrate backwards:

$$S(x)=S(x_0)+x_0-x+\int_{x_0}^x\eta(x)\ dx$$

> But I'm not sure how to compute this into some sort of closed form.

---

> Also accepting any proofs that this series doesn't have a closed form.
>
> By closed form, I mean something involving well-known constants such as $\pi,e,\gamma$, the Gamma function, the Reimann zeta function, and solutions to [algebraic differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_differential_equation) with algebraic initial conditions.

Comment: What do you mean with ‘solving the series’? Compute its sum?

Comment: Of course, I want to find its closed form.

Comment: not quite sure -- could we possibly use $(\ln x)' = 1/x$ to integrate the expression directly?

Comment: @gt6989b I'm not quite sure what you mean, could you elaborate?

Comment: possibly we can convert the sum to the integral somehow, then the denominator could integrate well? not sure, just throwing out ideas

Comment: mathemathica dont throw any answer. This make me think that probably (of course not sure) there is not a "closed" form in term of special functions... or at least if it exists is not evident.

Comment: I was thinking about letting $S(\infty)=0$ and then $$S(1)=\int_1^{\infty}(1-\eta(x))dx$$ but it doesn't seem to get any easier

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: It is naive to believe that this could have a closed form. And, after all, what is a closed form if it's not expressed as a combination of elementary functions? If I told you that the closed form is $\Xi ^2 _{8, 17} (x)$ would this make you happy? Using a letter for something that we do not know how to express (such as $\eta$) doesn't look satisfactory to me.

Comment: @AlexM. I'm just interested in this series.  If you could prove that a closed form doesn't exist, that'd be fine as well.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt How do you 'prove' that there is no closed form?

Comment: Closed forms aren't formal things. They are mostly conventions.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 We have an integral representation of our series, and integrals can be proven not to have elementary closed forms.  Look it up, I believe you'll want to find the Rische algorithm.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt The Risch algorithm works for _elementary_ functions. The Dirichlet eta function, for example, which you bring up in your question, is not elementary. You need to clearly specify what you mean by 'closed form'.

Comment: I mean it's quite unclear what you want here. I'm assuming you've checked Wolfram. If that doesn't give you anything, then it's highly unlikely anyone here will. Or, if someone does, it will likely be in terms of special functions beyond the scope of whatever algorithms Wolfram uses, hence certainly not a 'closed form' in any meaningful sense.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Ah.  I'm not familiar enough with the Risch algorithm to know how it works, else I would've already tried it out.  I don't think WA/Mathematica are good reasons for why there can't be a closed form.  It's easy enough with some complex analysis to make integrals with rather elementary solutions that WA can't solve.  By closed form, I mean something involving well-known constants such as $\pi,e,\gamma$ and [Liouvillian functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouvillian_function).

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Hm, actually, I think a solution involving functions that are solutions to algebraic differential equations with algebraic initial conditions would be more lenient.

Comment: Notice that the general term $\frac{1}{n\ln (n)}$ is decreasing and tends to zero as $n \rightarrow \infty$, so by the theory the series $S$ should converge. Probably you already know this then, I didn't quite understand why you're seeking that sort of solution. What do you mean by closed form?

Comment: @twinprime $\sum\frac1{n\ln n}$ can be shown to diverge.  Anyways, I'm searching for closed form because that's what I do when I tackle these problems.  Seen plenty of $\sum\frac1{n^a\ln^b(n)}$ problems, but never solved them.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n \ln n}$ can be shown to converge. Anyway, I can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly this series has an integral representation:
\begin{equation}
S = \int\limits_0^\infty \left[1+ Li_{1+\theta}(-1)\right] d\theta = 0.526412246533310410930696501411\dots
\end{equation}
Now using the integral representation of the poly-logarithm:
\begin{equation}
Li_{1+\theta}(-1) = -\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{t^\theta}{\theta!(1+\exp(t))} dt
\end{equation}
 and changing order of integration might be of some help.

On the other hand the original series converges quite slowly. After taking the first ten thousand terms only the first five digits are correct.

Comment: Hm, this does not seem to get any closer to a closed form though.  I can't see how you'd integrate that representation of the poly-log.

Comment: Doesn't look like this is headed towards a closed form solution.

Comment: Well, maybe it doesn't but at least we can compute the limit with high accuracy which is not possible using the series in question because it converges so slowly.

Comment: @AlexM. Actually, I'm specifically interested in $\int_0^1$ or $\int_1^\infty$